# Binding a command to a checkbox for onclick inside a xamdatagrid in wpf not working

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, mvvm, commandbinding

I have a checkbox inside my XamDataGrid , as follows :-

```
<igDp:UnboundField Width="1*" Label="{LocText props:Resources.GROUPLIST_SYNC}" BindingMode="TwoWay"  BindingPath="IsSynchronise.Value" Converter="{StaticResource BoolToUMDirectoryFilter}" ConverterParameter="Enabled"  ToolTip="{LocText props:Resources.GROUPLIST_SYNC}">
    <igDp:UnboundField.Settings>
        <igDp:FieldSettings AllowEdit="True">
            <igDp:FieldSettings.LabelPresenterStyle >
                <Style  TargetType="igDp:LabelPresenter"  BasedOn="{StaticResource GmsLabelStyle }">
                    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="Group_SYNC"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </igDp:FieldSettings.LabelPresenterStyle>
            <igDp:FieldSettings.CellValuePresenterStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDp:CellValuePresenter}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="igDp:CellValuePresenter">
                                <CheckBox Name="chkSynchronise"  IsChecked="{Binding Path=DataContext.DataItem.IsSynchronise.Value,  RelativeSource={ RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Command="{Binding SynchroniseGroups,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" >

                                </CheckBox>
                                <!--<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=DataContext.DataItem.IsSynchronise.Value, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={ RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"  
                                                           Command="{Binding SynchroniseGroups,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"
                                                          HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"  >

                                </CheckBox>-->
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </igDp:FieldSettings.CellValuePresenterStyle>
        </igDp:FieldSettings>
    </igDp:UnboundField.Settings>
</igDp:UnboundField>
```

So, how should I bind a command to checkbox in order to work it with click and get the behaviour of checked and unchecked inside my ViewModel? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to use the Command? You already bind the IsChecked property to something, the value change of that could be used to handle the click event logic

Comment: a basic checkbox does not have this command...change the self relativSource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*At first I want to add a side note:  Since infragistics release 14.2 the unbound field is obsolete [(look here)](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WPF/2014.2/CLR4.0/html/xamDataPresenter_Add_Unbound_Fields_to_a_DataPresenter_Control.html).*

For binding a boolean to the XamDataGrid I prefer using a [CheckBoxField](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WPF/2016.2/CLR4.0/html/InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v16.2~Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.CheckBoxField.html).

Class:

```
public class YourClass : NotificationObject
{
    private bool _checkBoxValue;

    public bool CheckboxValue
    {
        get
        {
            return this._checkBoxValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this._checkBoxValue != value)
            {
                this._checkBoxValue = value;

                // Do something: Event, Method, ...

                this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(this.CheckboxValue));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
 <igDp:FieldLayout>
     <igDp:CheckBoxField BindingType="UseAlternateBinding"
                         Name="CheckerField"
                         Label="YourCheckerFieldLabel"
                         ToolTip="YourTooltip"
                         AlternateBinding="{Binding CheckboxValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                         />
 </igDp:FieldLayout>
```